# python--rounding value of expression--unexpected EOF

Tags: python, rounding

In the last line I'm trying to round the output one decimal place but when i test this i get a unexpected EOF error. Help Please?

```
count = 0
scoreSum = 0
score = 0
while score != 999:
    score = float(input("Enter test score or enter 999 to finish: "))
    if score > 0 and score < 100:
        scoreSum += score
        count += 1
    elif (score <0 or score > 100) and score != 999:
        print("This score is invalid, Enter 0-100")
else:
    print ("your average is: ", round((scoreSum / count), 2)
```

Comment: This was too easy, you got 3 exactly the same answers within one minute :). Hit us with some better questions! I do admit that Python's error message is less than helpful.

Comment: haha, I'm only a beginner man, give it time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line is your problem--you need a closing parenthesis:

```
print ("your average is: ", round((scoreSum / count), 2))
#                                            right here ^
```

Actually, you could have your line of code be this:

```
print("your average is: ", round(scoreSum / count, 2))
```

There is no need for those extra parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Last line should be:

```
print ("your average is: ", round((scoreSum / count), 2))
```

You miss one closing parenthesis.

The complete error message was probably 'unexpected EOF while parsing', which is indeed a bit cryptic. Pro-tip: In future, if you find some error you do not understand, always [past the complete error message directly into Google](http://xkcd.com/627/). In most cases, someone else [already asked about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16327405/2647279).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of:

```
print ("your average is: ", round((scoreSum / count), 2))
                                                        ^ THIS
```